# Multi-dimensional array bug

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array, jodatime

It's an example hard to explain, but I have a problem with a multidimensional array acting weirdly. Here's the code:

```
public static void a(DateTime b, LocalTime c[][]){
    LocalTime d[] = c[b.getDayOfWeek() - 1];
    d[0] = c[b.minus(oneDay).getDayOfWeek() -1][0];
}
```

b is current DateTime, c is an array with workhours of a whole week.

After this code, we get:

```
c[b.getDayOfWeek() - 1][0] == c[b.minus(oneDay).getDayOfWeek() - 1][0]
```

It appears that setting d[0] also sets the value of

```
c[b.getDayOfWeek() - 1][0]
```

which shouldn't have happen. Any ideas why and how to prevent?

Comment: `d` and `c[b.getDayOfWeek() - 1]` reference the same memory. You did not copy the array, you copied the reference that points to it.

Comment: so how to copy it?

Comment: Use `System.arraycopy`

Comment: Yeah, i used `Array.copyOf` and it worked same, thanks!

Comment: Java does not really have multidimensional arrays. `c` is an array of `LocalTime[]` array references. After the first assignment, `d` and `c[b.getDayOfWeek() - 1]` are references to the same array.